# How to store audio input in an array from recorder?

Tags: java, android

I have been working on a project that implements pattern recognition on breathing patterns as a form of communication for speech impaired speakers.

I have an idea of how to do it, but I have a very basic knowledge of Java. I am stuck. I wanted to get the audio data from microphone and store it in an array. In doing so, I can then pass the data and normalise it, extract features from it, and then store the new array in my database.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Be sure the solutions are in PCM format.  MP3, AC3 or DTS formats will degrade the samples, since breaths are normally white noise. It would be easier to use a band around the chest to measure breathes(it would be more accurate). The one for USD $99 would be too expensive for mass deployment. Another solution would be, assuming tongue control, a series of T sounds, since they are easier to decode. This would allow Morse code,  but that only allows the basic Latin alphabet. What programming languages are you familiar with? We me be able to translate or adapt the code.

Comment: I have just been using matlab for simulation purposes. For the signal, I recorded a sample using microphone and store it as a variable. Then I filter the data to create smoother signal.

Answer (score 0):

**First you Should Encode To String**

```
  private void encodeAudio(String selectedPath) {
    
    byte[] audioBytes;
    try {
    
        // Just to check file size.. Its is correct i-e; Not Zero
        File audioFile = new File(selectedPath);
        long fileSize = audioFile.length();
    
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath));
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
            baos.write(buf, 0, n);
        audioBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    
        // Here goes the Base64 string
        _audioBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(audioBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        DiagnosticHelper.writeException(e);
    }
    
  }
```

- **Then Decode it in Received Device**

  ```
   private void decodeAudio(
           String base64AudioData, 
           File fileName, 
           String path,
           MediaPlayer mp) {

   try {

       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
       fos.write(Base64.decode(base64AudioData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
       fos.close();

       try {

           mp = new MediaPlayer();
           mp.setDataSource(path);
           mp.prepare();
           mp.start();

       } catch (Exception e) {

           DiagnosticHelper.writeException(e);

       }

    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  ```